# Error while inserting into table: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php

**I'm trying to insert data to database but i always get error**

What I'm doing wrong?

```
// Enter the new user in the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO policajt (meno, priezvisko, cislo_odznaku) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :co)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (policajt_id, username, heslo) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), :username, :password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':fname', $_POST['fname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lname', $_POST['lname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':co', $_POST['co'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if( $stmt->execute()):
        $message = 'Successfully created new user';
    else:
        $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
    endif;
```

When I run code, I get this error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're binding one query, then overwriting that with the second bind query. Prepare/bind/execute the first query, THEN prepare/bind/execute the second.

Answer (score 0):

In your insert statement you are not specifying the tokens for all fields that you want to do an insert for.

```
INSERT INTO policajt (meno, priezvisko, cislo_odznaku) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :co)
```

should be

```
  INSERT INTO policajt (meno, priezvisko, cislo_odznaku) VALUES (:meno, :fname, :lname, :co)
```